# Debugger does not recognize variable for return value of awaited method

Tags: microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, async-await, portable-class-library

I have this very simple code in portable class library targeted to .NET 4.5 and Windows Store Apps:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

When I put breakpoint on the second line and run my application the breakpoint is correctly hit but I cannot investigate response in the debugger because it reports:

> The name 'response' does not exist in the current context

I'm not sure how much is it related but I also had to disable *Just My Code* debugger setting in Debugger's settings to be able to debug my portable class library placed in the same solution as the executing application.

Is it some limitation of async-await methods, portable class libraries, targeted applications (Windows Store App particularly) or combination of those tools? Or is it a debugger bug? Any workaround would be more than helpful.

Comment: Use connect.microsoft.com to report problems like this.  They'll need a minimum repro project to take a look at it.

Comment: Do the standard reset: Clean, rebuild, ensure debug is enabled and if nothing else works reset VS. It should work.

Comment: @KasperHoldum: Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem. It only hepled to enable Just My Code again but the issue with debugger prevails. I was also trying to reproduce it on simple example and it of course works. Sending the whole project to MS for reproducing the issue is not an option. That is also the reason why I'm not planning to fill in connect report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this still happens with newer Visual Studio updates (I don't have that code base anymore) but the problem in my case was probably combining Async-Await debugging with code contracts. I haven't seen the problem when not using code contracts.

Comment: or Fody or other IL rewriting tools.

Comment: Darn you Code Contracts, I was beginning to like you. I can confirm that they are the problem. They must go away now.