# The name ... does not exist in the current context... how do we switch contexts?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, asynchronous, visual-studio-2015

I've put a break point into an anonymous method like this:

[image: Breakpoint in Anonymous Method]

How can I retrieve the value of the `configuration` variable in the watch window? It keeps complaining that "The name 'configuration' does not exist in the current context."

I imagine that that's because the current context is a thread that doesn't have that variable. How can I switch the context to see the value?

Comment: [Do you have anything that might be altering your IL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656978/debugger-does-not-recognize-variable-for-return-value-of-awaited-method)?

Comment: I don't have anything that I'm aware of that might be altering the IL.

Comment: Do you mean you know that you're not altering the IL, or that you don't know what can do the latter? Do you use Code Contracts, PostSharp, or anything like that?

Comment: I do know what intermediate language is. I'm not using Code Contracts, PostSharp, or anything like that.

Comment: Is this line throwing an error at runtime, or are you concerned with the value of configuration before this line is run?

Comment: It isn't throwing a runtime error. I'm concerned with the value.

Answer (score 3):

In your code snippet, it looks like `configuration` is being returned as a result of an [`await`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx) operation.  The line that is being executed is `await`ing the `configuration` result, and should not be executed until `configuration` is set.  When the breakpoint is first hit, however, `configuration` probably is not set yet.

UPDATE: to see the value of configuration, I presume that you can step over that line of code and `configuration` should be set to what it was then the line actually executed.

UPDATE: it looks like this is a [known issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1038150/visual-studio-2015-debugger-doesnt-recognize-a-variable) that has been [fixed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/01/16/visual-studio-2015-cpt-5-now-available.aspx).  Do you have the latest beta of VS2015?

Comment: I put a break point at the line of code that contains `configuration`, and then I stepped over that line. `configuration` still does not exist in the current context.